# How to create drop down list of all user in MVC5

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a few users with  roles created in my MVC 5 application. I have a ticket Model which contains basic ticket info. But now I want to add a property called "Assigned To" to this ticket Model and I want to assign this property value to the users available.

In my view I want to have a drop down list of all available Users so I can select a user to assign the ticket to. How can I create this property in my Model and how to make it a drop down list in my view? Thanks

**Update 1:**
in my Index() method I already have an existing actionresult model to return to view and its like this:

```
Models.Application model = db.Applications
            .Include("Source")
            .Include(.....)
            .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

        if (model == null)
        {
            return new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }

        return View(model);
```

How can I incorporate the code you suggest in the Index() method with what I already have?

Answer (score 0):

Query your database to get the list of users, then transpose this into your view model.  Make sure you DONT pass the User class directly from the DB as you will send the password, salt etc to the browser.   You should transpose it from a DB shape to a VM shape, containing only the fields required in the view.

ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel
{ 
     public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
     public string User { get; set;}
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel()
    {
         Users = <map users from db>
    };

    return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.User)
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.User, new SelectList(Model.Users, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OriginStation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
 </div>
```

Then your form postback handler:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.User now contains the id of the user
}
```

Comment: Hi, in my Index() method I already have an existing actionresult model to return to view. How can I incorporate the code you suggest in the Index() method with what I already have? Please see my **Update 1** in the question post.

Comment: The key to this problem is making sure you have a list of users in your view model, and the ``new SelectList`` part of the DropDownListFor. Can  I presume your Models.Application contains a list of users?

Comment: No. My **Models.Application** is contains only basic Ticket info. My problem is I don't know how to add list of user to this model.